# Logical fallacy that suggests $3/9=3/10$

Tags: decimal-expansion

I have seen that $3/9 = 1/3$ can be written as $0.3$. However, $0.3=3/10$. Does this mean that $3/9=3/10$, or am I confused?

Comment: who says  $\frac 13 = 0.3 ?$

Comment: Why the downvote?  Is there a rule that only PhDs in mathematics are allowed to ask questions?

Comment: Please don't say things that are just going to mislead @David

Comment: @DanielV While maybe it wasn’t phrased in the most robust/explicative manner, I think the comment was a good contribution.

Comment: I am going to take the liberty of significantly rewording this post without changing its gist in an effort to keep it from being closed, because I happen to think it has some merit to it $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @David I'm sorry I don't understand why you have linked Principle of Explosion here, and as a reply to what

Comment: " 0.3 repeating " is written as " 0.3 with a dot above 3"

Comment: Since the question has been changed the comment is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is that $1/3\ne 0.3$. So you find

$$\frac39=0.333\dots > 0.3 = \frac3{10}$$

which makes sense, since you're dividing by less. That is, $9$ is smaller than $10$, so $3/9 > 3/10$.

Comment: Lo and behold, an actual honest answer.  Thanks.

Comment: So 0.3 and 0.3 repeating are different values?

Comment: Yes, for sure.  You might see some people round down, but that loses some accuracy and it's not the same number anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is the difference between **equality** $=$ and **approximation** $\approx$. Here is what’s *actually* happening:

$$\frac39 = \frac13 = 0.33333\cdots \approx  0.3$$

The approximation comes when we **round down**.

Because we know that $0.3=3/10$, we can just replace $0.3$ with $3/10$ on the righthand side, giving us

$$\frac39 = \frac13 = 0.33333\cdots \approx \frac3{10}$$

We don’t need three names for the same value, so let’s take out the second two “equal to” terms:

$$\frac39 \approx \frac3{10}$$

Voilà! If you decide to use $=$ instead, that’s you’re prerogative, but in most instances it’s slightly wrong $\ddot\smile$